# Tabs names won't change on localisation

Tags: android, localization

I'm having very stupid problem, and I don't know is it some bug, or I am doing something wrong...

I have top class which extends TabActivity, and in that class I'm making two TabSpec objects with appropriate Activities to show.
In one of that classes I'm changing language by following code:

```
Locale appLoc = new Locale("fr");
Locale.setDefault(appLoc);
Configuration appConfig = new Configuration();
appConfig.locale = appLoc;
getResources().updateConfiguration(appConfig,
getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Everything works great, strings are changed, except Tabs names... I can go through my application, and nothing, it won't change.

When I enter application I have some progress bar which I dismiss later. 
When I exit from application by pressing home button, and enter once again, if progress bar is shown, tabs names will be changed, and if progress bar is not shown (i guess Android give me same instance of application), tabs names won't change.

Comment: How are you declaring the tabs and assigning their string values?

Comment: `TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
  firstTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");
  secondTabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tid1");

firstTabSpec.setIndicator(    getResources().getString(R.string.browse),...
secondTabSpec.setIndicator(  getResources().getString(R.string.search),...

tabHost.addTab(firstTabSpec);
tabHost.addTab(secondTabSpec);`

Comment: And you definitely declared `browse` and `search` in `res/values-fr/strings.xml`? Could you post the declaration?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

 <string name="app_name">Etno tour</string>
 <string name="package_str">package</string>
 <string name="browse">Browse-Fr</string>
 <string name="search">Search-Fr</string>

</resources>

Comment: Figured it out... After changing language, just call finish(); and  startActivity(new Intent(this, MyClass.class));

Answer (score 0):

```
if(sharedPreferenceHelper.getLanguage().equals("YOUR_LANG)){
   firstTabSpec.setIndicator("Match word to selected language");
else if(sharedPreferenceHelper.getLanguage().equals("OTHER_YOUR_LANGUAGE"){
   firstTabSpect.setIndicator("Match word to selected language 2");
```

...

Probably this is not right way! But it works for me.